# How to soft link an app to add it's shortcut to start menu in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, symbolic-link, tor

I'm launching tor browser from my home folder. I want it's shortcut to be placed in my start menu. I'm using xubuntu 18.04.

I tried the following but the shortcut is not appearing in start menu.

```
ln -s /path/to/start-tor-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
ln -s /path/to/start-tor-browser.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Here is the content of its .desktop file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./Browser/execdesktop
#
# This file is a self-modifying .desktop file that can be run from the shell.
# It preserves arguments and environment for the start-tor-browser script.
#
# Run './start-tor-browser.desktop --help' to display the full set of options.
#
# When invoked from the shell, this file must always be in a Tor Browser root
# directory. When run from the file manager or desktop GUI, it is relocatable.
#
# After first invocation, it will update itself with the absolute path to the
# current TBB location, to support relocation of this .desktop file for GUI
# invocation. You can also add Tor Browser to your desktop's application menu
# by running './start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'
#
# If you use --register-app, and then relocate your TBB directory, Tor Browser
# will no longer launch from your desktop's app launcher/dock. However, if you
# re-run --register-app from inside that new directory, the script
# will correct the absolute paths and re-register itself.
#
# This file will also still function if the path changes when TBB is used as a
# portable app, so long as it is run directly from that new directory, either
# via the shell or via the file manager.

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Tor Browser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=Tor Browser is +1 for privacy and -1 for mass surveillance
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;Security;
Exec=sh -c '"/home/user/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" --detach || ([ !  -x "/home/user/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/start-tor-browser" ] && "$(dirname "$*")"/Browser/start-tor-browser --detach)' dummy %k
X-TorBrowser-ExecShell=./Browser/start-tor-browser --detach
Icon=/home/user/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
StartupWMClass=Tor Browser
```

Comment: Could you please add the content of your `.desktop`-file to your question?

Comment: Copying the desktop file to usr/share/applications will make the application appear in the whisker menu. When I go home I'll elaborate a bit more if necessary.

Comment: @dsSTORM I tried it but still its not appearing in whisker menu.

Comment: Ok then, when I can I'll see if it can be done with menulibre, that should make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the desktop file you posted...

```
You can also add Tor Browser to your desktop's application menu
# by running './start-tor-browser.desktop --register-app'
```

So I'd say do what the file tells you to do and you should be able to see tor in the whisker menu.